# How to disable deprecated warnings in runtime php?

Tags: php, error-reporting

I want to supress warning from this `trigger_error('Deprecated', E_USER_DEPRECATED);` in runtime. From I have read I can use `error_reporting(E_ALL & -E_USER_DEPRECATED & -E_DEPRECATED);`. But that does not work. I tried if `error_reporting` works in general by using `error_reporting(0)`. This works. What did I miss? I did not find another way to solve my problem. And did not notice that this way does not work for someone else.

My code which does not suppress deprecated warning:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & -E_USER_DEPRECATED);
trigger_error('Deprecated', E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```

Php version: `7.0.14`.

Comment: I think what you want is a tilde, try `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the value for error_reporting(). To exclude certain errors you need to use the tilde symbol `~` instead of the dash `-`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
//                      ^ this one
trigger_error('Deprecated', E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```